# equality of norms

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

I have to show that $\| A\|_2=\sqrt{\| A^H\times A\|_2}$.

$A$ is a $n\times k$ matrix, $\| \cdot \|_2$ is defined as :

$$\| A\|_2=\sup\{ \|Ax\|, \|x\|\leq 1 \}$$

and $\| \cdot \|$ is the Euclidean norm of a vector.

I tried to solve it by the definitions of the norms but I can't conclude.

Any hint? 
Thank you !

Comment: Hint: $\| A \|_2^2$ is the largest eigenvalue of $A^H A$.

Comment: How is $A^H$ defined?

Comment: $A^H$ is the hermitian matrix of A.

Comment: Hint $||Ax||_2^2 = (Ax, Ax) = (A^HAx,x)$

Answer (score 0):

In the sequel, $x$ always denotes a unit vector.

$A^HA$ is a positive semidefinite matrix that is unitarily diagonalisable to an entrywise nonnegative eigenvalue matrix. It follows that both $x^H(A^HA)^2x$ and $x^HA^HAx$ are maximized at the same eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of $A^HA$, and $(\sup\{x^HA^HAx\})^2=\sup\{x^H(A^HA)^2x\}$. Hence $\|A\|_2^4=\|A^HA\|_2^2$.